# yeoman created application served by grunt and root paths

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

When one runs `grunt serve` from their yeoman created application, the node web server boots up and shows the application as expected.

When you view the generated source code from the server, it references 
`bower_components/bootstrap/js/####`, `scripts/main.js` and more, but looking in the "app" folder where the index.html and scripts/main.js is located, there is no bower_components there.

I notice when you run `grunt` that the generated application in the dist folder does include the bower_components and all required files, so that it could be run from any web server.

So the question is, when you run `grunt serve` how does grunt map all the files and folders? Where is this configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Gruntfile.js` there is a section called `connect` which manages the various server configurations including livereload, test and dist. Each of these connections has a middleware section where bower_components is mapped into the document root.

`livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),

              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];

          }

        }

      },`